# checking multiple check boxes automatically

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I am a PHP Programmer ,I want to know how to **programatically check multiple check boxes** when another  check box is checked by the user.Give me a link or you can give me a code to go through.

Comment: Isn't this JavaScript related?

Comment: I assume you are looking for a Javascript solution?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with PHP as it is running on the server side and has no direct influence on the user's browser elements like checkboxes.

Do this with JavaScript. I suggest using jQuery. Give every check box you want to check automatically a class like "auto-checked" and bind the click event on the "master" checkbox on a function that checks all check boxes that have the class "auto-checked".

```
$("#master-checkbox").bind("click", function() {
    $(".auto-checked").attr('checked','checked');
});
```

(not tested)

Also think of unchecking when clicking on the "master" again.

Comment: Not every little piece of script is worth importing jQuery for... There is still something out there called regular JavaScript.

Comment: Sure. But it makes things so much easier. Especially for beginners.

Comment: Sure, but the script isn't that hard to make. That way, you also learn some more about the basics of javascript, which will later help you understand more about other functions as well. Blindly adding jQuery will hardly teach you anything, imo. I use it as well for stuff like big carousels and slideshows, but where I can I try to write stuff by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a main checkbox, and if you check that you want to check all boxes with the classname `autocheck`.

On the main checkbox, you can add `onclick="checkAll()"` (where checkAll is just a function name I just made up). Then you can make that function, which should do the following:

1. see if the box is being checked or unchecked
2. if being checked: see which input elements have the class 'autocheck' and check them
3. if being unchecked: uncheck all

The script is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/FZRfx/2/